# Open batch file with/without argument

Tags: batch-file

How can I accommodate opening a batch file either with an argument

```
goto Item_%1
```

or without one?

```
set /p x=Select: 
goto Item_%x%
```

Comment: `If Not "%1"=="" goto somewhere`. The quotes exist so if no parameter it will be `""=""`.

Comment: or create a label `:Item_`, where you can ask the user.

Comment: I would always recommend, `If Not "%~1"=="" GoTo somewhere`, when you haven't got direct control over the input argument(s). It means that if the end user already doublequotes the argument, the expansion `~` will remove those other quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you aiming to achieve? 
My guess is a label targeting System that goes to a certain label when called.

If so, attempting to check %~1 if no parameter is sent will cause the batch to fail as the variable does not exist. 
IF NOT DEFINED %~1 does not get around this either.

The way to do it is to assign the label you wish to goto to a variable and Do an IF NOT DEFINED check on the variable- With enableDelayedExpansion

Example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
IF NOT DEFINED !LabelIS! GOTO default
IF DEFINED !LabelIS! GOTO !LabelIS!

:default
ECHO default starting label
pause 
exit

:target
ECHO Arrived at target
pause
exit
```

Note: If relying on user input to set the target, You'll need to vailidate that the input corresponds to a valid label.

Amendment:

```
If Not "%1"=="" goto somewhere
```

Is the wrong Syntax

The correct Syntax that will do what the question asked is:

```
If "%~1"=="" goto default
goto %~1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following checks the parameter or input by verifying that the corresponding label exists. If there is an empty input or the label does not exist, it keeps asking the user for the label, showing possible options. (As you probably don't want to show each label to the user ("internal" labels), you can hide some by just adding `<space>#` - a label is a single word only, everything after the first space is ignored, but can be used to distiguish them)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "label=%~1"
:retry #
findstr /ix ":%label%" "%~f0" && goto %label%
echo Invalid or no Label given: [%label%]. Possible options:
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /xr ":.*[^#]$" "%~f0"') do echo/  %%a
set /p "label=Label? "
goto :retry

:Item_1
echo reached Item_1
goto :eof

:anotherlabel
echo reached anotherlabel
goto :eof

:errorhandling #
echo to demonstrate a hidden label
goto :eof
```